# AutoMapper settings properties to null on destination object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have something like this:

```
public class DomainEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DomainOtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DomainAnotherEntity> AnotherEntities { get; set; }
}

public class ApiEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int OtherEntitiesCount { get; set; }
}
```

And following mapper configuration:

```
Mapper.Configuration.AllowNullCollections = true;

Mapper.CreateMap<DomainEntity, ApiEntity>().
    ForSourceMember(e => e.OtherEntities, opt => opt.Ignore()).
    ForSourceMember(e => e.AntherEntities, opt => opt.Ignore()).
    ForMember(e => e.OtherEntitiesCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherEntities.Count()));

Mapper.CreateMap<ApiEntity, DomainEntity>().
    ForSourceMember(e => e.OtherEntitiesCount, opt => opt.Ignore()).
    ForMember(e => e.OtherEntities, opt => opt.Ignore()).
    ForMember(e => e.AnotherEntities, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

To get the ApiEntity from the DomainEntity I'm using `var apiEntity = Mapper.Map<DomainEntity, ApiEntity>(myDomainEntity);`

To get the merged DomainEntity from an ApiEntity I'm using `var domainEntity = Mapper.Map(myApiEntity, myDomainEntity);`

But when using this, the properties `OtherEntities` and `AnotherEntities` are set to `null` - even when they had values before calling the mapping from `myApiEntity` to `myDomainEntity`. How can I avoid this so they really **merge** and not just replacing values?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of `AutoMapper` are you using? Your scenario works ok for me on `2.2.1`.

Comment: I'm using the latest version available on NuGet which is currently 2.2.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for `UseDestinationValue` instead of `Ignore`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApiEntity, DomainEntity>().
    ForSourceMember(e => e.OtherEntitiesCount, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue()).
    ForMember(e => e.OtherEntities, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue()).
    ForMember(e => e.AnotherEntities, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
```