# How do I ignore a destination object property with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I've found what is either a bug with AutoMapper or some convention-based behavior that I need to override. The code below reproduces the issue. How do I keep AutoMapper from trying to write to the `FooType` property in the scenario below?

```
    [Test]
    public void FooTypeShouldNotBeAltered()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(typeof (TypeB), typeof (TypeA))
            .ForMember("Foo", opt => opt.MapFrom("Foo"));

        var typeA = new TypeA { FooType = "foo" };
        var typeB = new TypeB { Foo = "bar" };

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(typeB, typeA, typeof (TypeB), typeof (TypeA));

        Assert.AreEqual("foo", typeA.FooType);
    }

    public class TypeA
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public string FooType { get; set; }
    }

    public class TypeB
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the output of the test:

```
Expected string length 3 but was 13. Strings differ at index 0.
Expected: "foo"
But was:  "System.String"
-----------^
```

(For what it's worth, it's clear to me (though not necessarily completely demonstrated by this code) that AutoMapper is setting the value of the `FooType` property to the typename of the `Foo` property.)

For now I'm looking for a way to stop this from happening without using generics-based overloads or custom resolvers, and I need to use the `Map(source, dest, sourceType, destType)` overload to execute the actual mapping.

Comment: There is plenty of answer on this subject. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052579/automapper-how-to-ignore-property-in-source-item-that-does-not-exist-in-destinat

Comment: SO correctly shows this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125997/automapper-settings-properties-to-null-on-destination-object as related, but the options I have don't include 'UseDestinationValue'. I'm guessing I have to write a custom IValueResolver or use one of the included resolvers... but which one?

Comment: Yes, I've been sitting in front of the computer too long, mapping back and forth between sources and destinations.... thanks.